# Contacting editor-in-chief regarding delay ?

Tags: peer-review

I have a paper in review in a prestigious applied math journal. The average time from first submission to final decision in that journal is about 8 months.

The first round of reviews took 7 months. After submitting revision in less that 2 months, we have been waiting for another 6 months.

The only point of contact available directly is the editorial staff, who reply promptly that "The tardy reviewer will soon send out their review". This has been going on for last 4 months. I do not know the identity of handling editor.

Can/should I contact editor-in-chief to help speed up the process ?
13 months of review is ridiculous in my field, and almost unheard of.

Comment: 13 months is pretty normal in pure math (not sure about applied).  I don't think there is much you can do to speed it up, short of withdrawing your paper and submitting it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Nate. As I mentioned, the average time is 8 months to final decision, so 13 is certainly very rare. Also, do you think I should contact editor-in-chief ?

Comment: These distributions have heavy tails, so if 8 months is the average then 13 is not too unusual.  I don't think contacting the editor-in-chief will accomplish anything.